# An Asimov story where the fact that "committee" has three double letters plays a role

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

This is not really an SF question, but about a short story by Isaac Asimov, so I think it fits. In one of his many "mysteries", someone asks for a rather short word with three double letters in it.

I don't remember  whether it is among the Black Widowers, or the Union Club or any other series of this kind. Or maybe even among the Azazel ones, in which case it would be either Fantasy of SF, (depending on whether Azazel is a demon or a creature from a more advanced civilisation, an ambiguity the Good Doctor insists on maintaining).
Anyway, I would like to find the title of this story.

---

*Edit: I have been racking my brain about Paulie_D vs Clara Diaz Sanchez, and something came back.
The fact that the word was "committee" rather than bookkeeper or any other one was not important *per se*. The point was that there was a brilliant but surly kid who had a clue but he refused to tell it to adults, considering them all as idiots. Until one adult was bright enough to guess his enigmas, I think there were more than just the one about "committee", and he agreed to tell him his clue.*

Comment: The trick answer is "woollen". That kind of humour would probably have appealed to the good doctor.

Comment: But "woollen" has only two double letters, not three.

Comment: It has a double-u - BOOM, BOOM!! :-)

Comment: I've been through the six *Black Widowers* books. There are several stories involving word puzzles, but none with three pairs of letters.

Comment: Maybe it's one of the Fleming Stone stories by Carlolyn Wells. In one, solving a crime hinged on the misspelling of committee as "comite" (it revelead that the person who wrote the letter was French). Not really science fiction though.

Comment: The only one that I'm aware of is "bookkeeper"

Comment: http://www.benespen.com/journal/2017/4/19/the-long-view-richard-feynman-and-isaac-asimov-on-spelling-reform Asimov was interested in real-world spelling reform.

Comment: I've also checked the *Union* stories in the collection [The Union Club Mysteries](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872942.The_Union_Club_Mysteries) and none of them match. There are a load of Union stories that were never collected and I don't have copies of those.

Comment: I am positive it is an Asimov story. It might just have been "bookkeeper" rather than "committee" but I doubt it. I don't remember whether it was in a collection. As John Rennie says it might be a Union Club story that was never collected. Sigh...

Comment: *Bookkeeper* is the only word that has three **consecutive** double letters, but there are lots of words that have three double letters that aren't consecutive.

Comment: I wonder if this will ever be solved successfully.

Comment: @JohnRennie for reference, more common such words are: successfully, committee, sleeplessness, suddenness, aggressiveness, stubbornness, bookkeeping, addressee, bookkeeper, whippoorwill, Mississippi.

Comment: Did rhe committee meet in Tennessee, or maybe Mississippi?

Comment: I made a full-text search on all of Asimov's short stories. Neither "committee" nor "bookkeeper" is used in that sense.

Comment: @JohnRennie can we use spoiler tags in comments?   sadly no.

Comment: OK, there are many such words. Maybe having 3 double letters and *exactly* 3 single *different* letters was part of the question ? If that was indeed part of the question, words of 10 letters or more are out, and unless I missed something all 9 letter words but committee in the comments above have one of the "single" letters identical to one of the double ones, always a third "e" disconnected from the doublet "ee".

Comment: @Ubik Thanks for your full-text search. So the "committee" stuff is not in Asimov at all. I have absolutely no idea where I have picked it up, it clearly mixed up in my mind with the "The 12-year-old problem".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Twelve Years Old](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story373.html). (AKA The 12 Year Old Mystery)
The Union Club Mysteries.

> Griswold manages to outsmart a twelve-year-old smart alek who knows an English word which is short, simple, common and cannot be pronounced if written all in capitals.
>
> The word, of course, is “POLISH,” because it’s pronounced one way if spelled “polish” and another if spelled “Polish,” as any twelve-year-old smart alek knows. Asimov dealt with innumerable such creatures over the course of his career—including, alas, myself—so this is one way for him to get back at them. It’s relatively pleasant as Union Club mysteries go.

I don't recall if "committee" was part of it. It's possible that you are conflating two stories. But I think the smart-alec kid is the one you want.

Comment: Oddly, another example struck me the other day: [Wear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Wear) rhymes with ‘hear’, while [wear](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear#English) rhymes with ‘hair’.

Comment: Asimov used the same polish/Polish idea in one of the Black Widowers stories but as dinner table conversation, not the solution to the problem (although I think it provided a clue). The wordplay must have definitely appealed to him.

Comment: @Gidds or reading (pronounced ree-ding) as oppose to Reading (Red-ing)  in both PA & England

Comment: Polish up this answer just a bit and it will be perfect!

Comment: How about 'herb' which an American couldn't pronounce if it was written in capitals but a British person could? We pronounce the plants and the man's name the same way.

Comment: @Thierry You said that purely for the pun's sake, I assume? Or is there anything you actually want improved?

Comment: Yes this is the smart alec kid story I remembered Polish VS polish and not committee. I must have conflated two stories

Comment: @EgorHans Yes just for the pun's sake. The answer is fine (I gave it +1), but the quoted part is clearly not exactly correct and I don't see what writing in all caps has to do with anything: READ, WOUND, BOW, DOVE, etc also fit the bill. Maybe I have to read the story to fully get it.

Comment: @Thierry, the point is that there are two words, polish (to make something shine) and Polish (originating in Poland). The words are written the same, except for the initial capital. They are pronounced differently. If you see it written in lowercase, you can tell whether it is polish or Polish.  But if you see it written in uppercase you can't  tell. WOUND, for instance, is an ambiguity in either upper or lower case. But POLISH is only ambiguous in uppercase. As pointed out above, it also applies to the town of Reading which is pronounced Red-ding.

Comment: @Pete I think I get it. The idea is that POLISH is ambiguous but polish isn't, whereas, say, BOW and bow are both ambiguous? That makes sense but that's not what the quote in the answer says. That says that Polish is pronounced in only one way, which isn't true (thus my initial comment).

Comment: But I realize if we're talking about individual words without context, for example as listed in a dictionary, then Polish has only one pronunciation and the quote makes more sense. I think your explanation in your last comment is clearer than the one you quoted in your answer, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 17):

It could be [*Encyclopedia Brown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_Brown) by  Donald J. Sobol

Encyclopedia Brown is a series of books featuring the adventures of boy detective Leroy Brown, nicknamed "Encyclopedia" for his intelligence and range of knowledge

> A contest is held in which contestants complete a quiz for 3 secret
> prizes for 1st, 2nd and 3rd place. The first place winner receives the
> best prize: a watch, which he discovers has been broken. The theory of
> the crime is one of the contestants secretly examined the prizes and
> played with the watch and broke it. The culprit turns out to be the
> 2nd place girl that purposely missed a question she should have gotten
> right: "Name a word that has three double-letters." The girl referred
> to herself as a "bookkeeper". Assuming she remembered such a fact, the
> solution fails to prove why she threw the contest or definitively
> eliminate her from the suspect pool of the other contest losers.

Comment: One of my favourite series when I was a kid.

Comment: I miss being able to say a plot was [Encyclopedia Browned](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EncyclopediaBrowned) or that [Bugs Meany is Gonna Walk](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BugsMeanyIsGonnaWalk) (TvTropes links!)

Comment: Encyclopedia Brown: The smartest man in the whole damn town.

Comment: This is undoubtedly the correct answer. I loved Encyclopedia Brown, and the word "bookkeeper" has been stuck in my brain for 30 years.